# Array contains only one item even though I add multiple objects

Tags: ios, nsarray

I want to read one data array in iOS, but I read only one record in this array, I checked the array and it contains 10 items.

```
for(NSString *po in list) {
    infor.poster = [po valueForKey:@"Poster"];
    infor.vName= [po valueForKey:@"VName"];
    infor.name = [po valueForKey:@"Name"];
    infor.HDtrailerPath = [po valueForKey:@"HDTrailerPath"];

    [arrfilm addObject:infor];
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    int widthlblscroll = 0;
    for (Inforfilm *u in arrfilm) {
        Inforfilm *infoF = [[Inforfilm alloc]init];
        infoF.poster = [u valueForKey:@"poster"];
        infoF.name = [u valueForKey:@"name"];

        NSLog(@"%@",infoF.poster);
        NSLog(@"%@",infoF.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were adding the very same instance of `Inforfilm` multiple times to your array. Just because you update its properties does not mean it is a new instance. To prevent this, instanciate a new instance on every loop iteration. as done in the inner first line.

```
for(NSString *po in list) 
{
    //create a new instance of Inforfilm 
    Inforfilm *infor = [[Inforfilm alloc] init];    
    infor.poster = [po valueForKey:@"Poster"];
    infor.vName= [po valueForKey:@"VName"];
    infor.name = [po valueForKey:@"Name"];
    infor.HDtrailerPath = [po valueForKey:@"HDTrailerPath"];

    [arrfilm addObject:infor];
    //make sure you got ARC enabled, otherwise this object will now leak!
}
```

Comment: thanks Till i checked and edit it, base error :D thank so much Till